# How to access GetLocaleInfo from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, locale

I'm converting a routine from VB6 (a language I do not know) to C#.    In the VB6 code it has . . .

```
LCID = GetThreadLocale        
rc = GetLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, data, dataLen)
```

So in my C#, in the class body, I've added

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetThreadLocale();
```

. . . which seems to allow me to make the first call.

But in Googling *GetLocaleInfo()* I see conflicting information.   On the web, in addition to the plain, vanilla *GetLocaleInfo()*, there's also :

In http://www.webtropy.com/articles/art9-1.asp?f=GetLocaleInfo it refers to something called **GetLocaleInfA()**.

And in this StackOverflow question [Windows: Get LCID from locale string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240556/windows-get-lcid-from-locale-string) there's a mention of a **GetLocaleInfoEx()**.

How do I know which one to use, and how do I set it up to be called?  (BTW, I'll also need to do the same thing for *SetLocaleInfo()* .

Comment: Just don't.  Use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator instead.

Comment: @HansPassant When I looked on MSDN it wasn't obvious how to use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator to set the new separator for the thread like _SetLocaleInfo()_ does.  When you call _SetLocaleInfo()_ then any formatting calls made afterwards use the new setting.   Could you show or link to an example showing how to do that with CultureInfo?

Comment: Is Google down today?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692840/c-sharp-cultureinfo-numberformat-numberdecimalseparator-problem

Answer (score -1):

Use the proper .NET Framework method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.CultureInfo.LCID;

Comment: I didn't see an example in that link of how to do the equivalent of _SetLocaleInfo_ using LCID.   If I'm currently in a lnaguage, e.g., German, where "," is the decimal separator, how do I use LCID to set it to use "."?