# How to get and set decimal separator in C# using CultureInfo

Tags: c#, localization

I'm converting a routine from VB6 (a language I do not know) to C#. In the VB6 code it uses *GetLocaleInfo()* and *SetLocaleInfo()* and I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561364/how-to-access-getlocaleinfo-from-c-sharp) to ask how to do this in C# and I was told to use "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator" instead.

For my purposes I'm only interested in getting the decimal separator **and setting it** for whatever my current locale is.   Following the links in the answers to the original question it wasn't obvious how to do this.

In the original code the programmer uses the American "." format internally for lots of string formatting and building so he first gets the current locale's separator (say, ",")  and saves it, then he sets the current locale to use "." and does all his stuff, then he sets it back to what he saved when he finishes.  My marching orders are to stick as closely as possible to the original design, which is why I asked about *GetLocaleInfo()* and *SetLocaleInfo()*, but if someone could show how to do this CultureInfo I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT:  I don't understand what people don't like about this question.**  I also don't understand what code people are looking for.  This is all the code there is in the VB6

```
 LCID = GetThreadLocale 
 rc = SetLocaleInfo(LCID, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, ".")
```

That **is** the code.  I want to do the same thing in C#.    My understanding from our VB6 programmer is that it gets the current locale setting (say, German) and says *regardless of the fact that German uses "," as a decimal separator, we are going to use "."*.

Comment: Instead of posting some vague description of the code, you should post the code itself. Show your effort at translation so far.

Comment: What code do you need to see?  I want to know how to do the equivalent of _GetLocaleInfo()_ and _SetLocaleInfo()_ using CultureInfo.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking for the "NumberDecimalSeparator" property of the "NumberFormatInfo" object (System.Globalization), as you mentioned.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) the msdn article on it.  The usage (from the msdn page) is as follows:

```
// Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
  NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

  // Displays a value with the default separator (".").
  Int64 myInt = 123456789;
  Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

  // Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
  nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = " ";
  Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
```

You can change the separator with the NumberDecimalSeparator = "" line as seen above.  All of your numeric outputs will use the separator as specified.

Likewise, you can use the NumberGroupSeparator property to handle the separation of whole number digits:

```
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

...will make "123,456,789" display as "123.456.789", etc.

Hopefully that is a more clear and concise explanation than the one you linked.

Comment: What is the scope of NumberFormatInfo in the above example?   In other words if I set the separator to a "." using the above technique does it set it for all formatting calls in that thread, in the process, the whole PC or what?  _SetLocaleInfo_ seems to set it for the thread.

Comment: It is scoped equivalently to other local variables:  To the current instance of the class unless static, then to all instances of the same.  Since you would be creating a new instance of a class for a threading scenario (to my understanding), you would need to declare it static in the class definition or specify it for a new instance.  I haven't done much work with threading, so someone else may have a better answer for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a replacement for _SetLocaleInfo()_.  When you call SetLocaleInfo() saying to use "." then all the other formatting method calls in that thread respect that new setting.

Comment: My answer is exactly that.  Edit your question with your code, throw in a couple comments about what you're trying to do more specifically, and I'll edit my answer with your own code sample to help you out.  As it is, it's a bit hard - that's why people are asking for more details.  I'll be glad to do what I can, but I need a bit more to work with to help further.

Comment: What code?  I'm looking for a replacement for a single function call.  I was told by two people in the other question to not use _SetLocaleInfo()_, but instead to use the CultureInfo class.  If you call _SetLocaleInfo()_ and tell it that the current language will use ".", even if it's some European language that uses "," for a decimal separator then everything in that thread which formats numeric strings will use ".".   I'm perfectly happy to use _SetLocaleInfo()_ but I was told it's not the done thing in .Net.

Comment: Oh, now I see why you are confused as to what code people are asking for!  That snippet is a little helpful, but your question poses that portion well enough without it.  What I think we are all looking for is a coded example of what you're trying to do:  For example, if you want to set locale-specific settings and have them update dynamically, show us (with comments replacing the parts you don't understand, if needed) what you've done so far in the C# rewrite.  I'll try to build you an example a bit later based on what I think you are looking for.